# Get earliest date with group by- SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the earliest **Created Date** with group by **identity number**. Here the sample of record.

```
| AccountID | DisplayName   | CreatedDate | IdentityNumber | OrganizationID |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|----------------|----------------|
| 1         | John          | 1 Jan 2018  | 1234           | 1000           |
| 2         | John          | 15 Jan 2018 | 1234           | 1001           |
| 3         | John          | 20 Jan 2018 | 1234           | 1002           |
| 4         | Michael       | 1 Jan 2018  | 1235           | 1000           |
| 5         | Michael       | 3 Jan 2018  | 1235           | 1003           |
| 6         | Wood          | 2 Jan 2018  | 1236           | 1002           |
```

So I want to produce the result like this.

```
| AccountID | DisplayName   | CreatedDate | IdentityNumber | OrganizationID |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|----------------|----------------|
| 1         | John          | 1 Jan 2018  | 1234           | 1000           |
| 4         | Michael       | 1 Jan 2018  | 1235           | 1000           |
| 6         | Wood          | 2 Jan 2018  | 1236           | 1002           |
```

This my sql snippet

```
SELECT IdentityNumber, MIN(CreatedDate)
FROM Accounts
GROUP BY IdentityNumber
```

And yes I can get the earliest record with group by identity number. But how I can grab the AccountID, DisplayName, OrganizationID without **group by**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is using the `WITH TIES` clause in concert with `Row_Number()`

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  dbo.Accounts
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By IdentityNumber Order By CreatedDate)
```

Comment: @Chuki2 Yup.  Tha'ts me in 4 words  :)

Comment: what a much nicer way of doing it without a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY IdentityNumber
                                    ORDER BY CreatedDate)
    FROM dbo.Accounts
)
SELECT  AccountID,
        DisplayName,
        CreatedDate,
        IdentityNumber,
        OrganizationID 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MIN keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT [AccountID],[DisplayName],MIN([CreatedDate]),[IdentityNumber],[OrganizationID] FROM dbo.[Accounts]
GROUP BY [IdentityNumber]
```

the above code will return

| AccountID | DisplayName | CreatedDate | IdentityNumber | OrganizationID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 Jan 2018 | 1234 | 1000 |
| 4 | Michael | 1 Jan 2018 | 1235 | 1000 |
| 6 | Wood | 2 Jan 2018 | 1236 | 1002 |